# How to process a "Very Large image file" in MATLAB and find out the pixel with largest value

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have to process a very large image ( say 10 MB image file or even more).I have to remove artifacts and dead pixels in MATLAB

I have read about Block Processing of Large Images, but have no idea how to apply it to a 16 bit image. 
I am referring to removal of pixels which have highest value into the average value of surrounding pixel .my code is not working on my image which is 80 MB of size

```
    numIterations = 30;
    avgPrecisionSize = 16; % smaller is better, but takes longer

    % Read in the image grayscale:
    originalImage = double(rgb2gray(imread('C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\TM\image5.tif')));

    % get the bad pixels where  = 0 and dilate to make sure they get everything:
    badPixels = (originalImage == 0);
    badPixels = imdilate(badPixels, ones(12));

    %# Create a big gaussian and an averaging kernel to use:
    G = fspecial('gaussian',[1 1]*100,50);
    H = fspecial('average', [1,1]*avgPrecisionSize);

    %# User a big filter to get started:
    newImage = imfilter(originalImage,G,'same');
    newImage(~badPixels) = originalImage(~badPixels);

    % Now average to
    for count = 1:numIterations
    newImage = imfilter(newImage, H, 'same');
    newImage(~badPixels) = originalImage(~badPixels);
    end

    %% Plot the results
    figure(123);
    clf;

    % Display the mask:
    subplot(1,2,1);
    imagesc(badPixels);  
    axis image
    title('Region Of the Bad Pixels');

    % Display the result:
    subplot(1,2,2);
    imagesc(newImage);
    axis image
    set(gca,'clim', [0 255])
    title('Infilled Image');

    colormap gray
    newImage2 = roifill(originalImage, badPixels);

    figure(44);
    clf;
    imagesc(newImage2);
    colormap gray
```

Comment: Voting to close.  Insufficient information to diagnose the problem, not even sure there is a (programming) problem.  To convince this reader you'll have to post some code and explain clearly how it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the image format? What is your definition of "dead pixel"? What artifacts do you want to remove? Why do you say 10MB is large? Is there a performance or memory limitation that causes you to ask this question on SO? Do you have the image processing toolbox? Have you done any work on this topic that failed to asccomplish this fairly basic task in a satisfactory manner? Do you see now why your question will be closed soon?

Comment: I would be obliged to close too, if not edited with more details as mentioned by @RodyOldenhuis.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have edited my post now .. the only problem I am facing is my image is really large it can be viewed by using IMTOOL but cannot be processed using above code .. OUT of memory error comes.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I have edited my post now . help me out with processing of large images.

Comment: You need to define "not working on my image".  Do you run out of memory, or get some other error?

Comment: So, you mean to do something like [apply a median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter)?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes .. But problem is my image is very large

Comment: @nkjt its just out of memory error .. image is large .. I can view it using imtool in matlab but I m finding a way out to process it.

Comment: check out this link (its easy to view but processing that large image is tough) http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/08/05/dealing-with-really-big-images-viewing/

Comment: @Tanya: I don't get it; 10 MB is not that large; my phone's camera can make pictures larger than that...Also, my SLR camera can spit out (RAW) images over 100 MB...it's really not that big...?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis yes 10MB or more than that .. Matlab doesn't process such large image at one go with the code i provided above but it does have block processing using blockproc function .. but that is pretty complex.Is there any other way out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a few things which are obvious problems (but it might depend specifically on how far you can get into the code before you run out of memory)

1) You are immediately converting the whole image to `double`

2) You are identifying certain pixels which you want to replace, but passing the whole image to `imfilter` and then throwing away (presumably) most of the output:

```
newImage = imfilter(originalImage,G,'same');  % filter across the entire image
newImage(~badPixels) = originalImage(~badPixels);  % replace all the good pixels!
```

Without converting to double, why not first check where the bad pixels are, do your processing on subregions of the appropriate size around those pixels (the subregions can be converted to double and back), and then reassemble the image at the end?

`blockproc` may work if you can write your filtering option as a function which takes in an image area and returns the correct area - you'll have to use the `border_size` option appropriately and make sure your function just returns the original image without bothering to do any filtering if it hits a block with no bad pixels in.  You can even have it write out to file as well.